# Implementing the UIPageViewController

Tags: swift

I read that :

Create a class named `PageViewController` and set it as subclass of     `UIPageViewController`.
Once created, adopt the `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` protocol and then we have:

```
class PageViewController:UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource
```

Next, implement the two required methods of the UIPageViewControllerDataSource protocol :

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    var index = (viewController as PageContentViewController).index

    index++

    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)

}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    var index = (viewController as PageContentViewController).index

    index--

    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)

}
```

Thus, my question is :

**How** the **arguments**(**parameters**) of these funcs ( **pageViewController** and **viewController**) being passed to themselves given that there aren't previous statements of these ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common pattern in the Apple APIs. It is used often for delegates and data sources. You can look at it this way: `ObjectA` is an object that has a data source called `DataSourceA`. `ObjectA` is going to be calling methods on `DataSourceA` in order to get information about what data to display. When `ObjectA` calls the method in `DataSourceA` it passes all the information that `DataSourceA` needs in order to return the necessary data. That way, `DataSourceA` doesn't need to maintain its own references to any of the objects that it will be configuring.

In your example, the `pageViewController` argument is actually the `UIPageViewController` itself. The `UIPageViewController` is going to pass itself as the first parameter argument. The `viewController` argument is the view controller that is currently being displayed by the `UIPageViewController`. Keep in mind that the `UIPageViewController` stores the displayed view controller in its `viewControllers` property. So even though you can't see where that `viewController` property is defined, the `UIPageViewController` does have a reference to it.

Comment: HI Roman..,first, thanks for your reply. Since you said that, can you suggest me a weblink where explain in detail this common pattern for delegate and data source ?

Comment: This is a link to the official Apple documentation on the topic: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH11